# Set Page Background Color for Entire Crystal Report

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report that was designed in CR Developer for Visual Studio (I'm using VS 2017, and the CR Developer is version SP23).

I'm looking for a way to change the color of the page.  I can change each individual section and field, but what happens is between the last detail section and the page/report footer, only white shows.  I figure that if I could somehow set the page background color, then even the blank sections of the page would still be colored.

Here is an example of what I'm talking about:
[image: Sample Report]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you don't have data on those sections ? Can't you supress them ? Maybe i'm not understanding... you are using a formula to change the background color of each section right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a background color image in page header and set it to 'Underlay Following Sections'.

Comment: Brilliant.  Starting with your suggestion I was able to make it one step easier - I was able to add a box object to the page header, set its background color, and then drag and extend it to the bottom of the page footer.  Super easy and works perfectly.  Thanks!!